# Can not promisifyAll Redis api with Bluebird in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, promise, bluebird

I am unable to make Redis api to promisifyAll in typescript.

```
import * as redis from 'redis';
import {RedisClient} from 'redis';
import * as Promise  from 'bluebird';

Promise.promisifyAll(redis);
const client: RedisClient = redis.createClient(CacheConfig);
```

I am getting the following typescript error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> getting the following (tslint)error.

Stuff that mutates objects at runtime is not well supported by the TypeScript's (static) type system. `PromisifyAll` magically inserts new functions, but these new magic functions do not become a part of the existing interfaces (in this case `RedisClient`). You need to extend the `RedisClient` interface *manually*.

PS: 
Not a `tslint` error. Its a `typescript` error.

Comment: Thank you @Basarat. Give me a sample to extend the `RedisClient` interface myself.